# How can i update one specific dotnet assembly in Universal Windows Platform app?

Tags: .net, nuget, windows-10, uwp, .net-core

I read that dotnet goes OpenSource and is distributed via granular packages via nuget instead of monolith installer.

I create a simple UWP application and what i see inside project.json is

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

When i try to install prerelease System.Collections via nuget i get following

```
Version conflict detected for System.Private.Uri. 
 SM.W10 (≥ 1.0.0) -> System.Collections (≥ 4.0.11-beta-23516) -> System.Runtime (≥ 4.0.21-beta-23516) -> System.Private.Uri (≥ 4.0.1-beta-23516) 
 SM.W10 (≥ 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (≥ 5.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime (≥ 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR-arm (≥ 1.0.0) -> System.Private.Uri (= 4.0.0).
```

I feel that i should somehow unwrap `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` but it has many levels of nesting and only deeply nested `Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR-arm` has strict version for System.Private.Url

Is there any way to update System.Collections without pain ?

Comment: I think you can put an entry under dependencies referring to the System.Collection release you want.  Just put it under the .NetCore entry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For its first release UWP apps pinned all the core packages because of some private dependencies between packages like `System.Runtime` or `System.Collections` and the .NETNative toolchain.  As a result to test out a new version of any of the lowest-level contracts you also need to update the runtime package.

For example.

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0"
  "Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime": "1.0.1-beta-23516",
  "System.Collections" :  "4.0.11-beta-23516"
}
```

You'll only run into this behavior for packages at the very bottom of our stack, specifically

```
System.Collections,
System.Diagnostics.Contracts,
System.Diagnostics.Debug,
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace,
System.Diagnostics.Tools,
System.Diagnostics.Tracing,
System.Globalization,
System.Globalization.Calendars,
System.IO,
System.ObjectModel,
System.Reflection,
System.Reflection.Extensions,
System.Reflection.Primitives,
System.Resources.ResourceManager,
System.Runtime,
System.Runtime.Extensions,
System.Runtime.Handles,
System.Runtime.InteropServices,
System.Text.Encoding,
System.Text.Encoding.Extensions,
System.Threading,
System.Threading.Tasks,
System.Threading.Timer
```

Future releases of UWP won't have this same issue.  We found that using NuGet to try to enforce the private dependencies was fragile and produced confusing errors.